# adding objects to a property of an array

Tags: php, laravel

I'm adding an property to an object, and in this property I want to add different objects.

Code:

```
            // For each room grab the pins.
            foreach($rooms as $room) {

                // Grab all inspiration_id's for a specific room.
                $pins = Pins::where('room_id', $room['id'])->get();

                // Inspirations array.
                $inspirations = array();


             // For each pin use inspiration_id to grab inspiration id.
                foreach($pins as $pin) {

                    // Grab inspiration that matches the pin.
                    $pin = Inspirations::where('id', $pin['inspiration_id'])->get();

                    // Add a $pin to the array.
                    array_push($inspirations, $pin);

                }

                // Input inspirations into pins of this room.
                $room['pins'] = $inspirations;

            }
```

Example of current output below:
[image]

**The problem is:**
I want an inspiration to be added to pins as an object, now there is still an extra array around each inspiration. I really want to achieve the below result: Instead of what is shown in the image.

```
pins [
   {
     id: 1,
     ...
   },
   {
     id: 2,
     ...
   }
]
```

Comment: Right way is to use Relations. Read the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Inspirations::where('id', $pin['inspiration_id'])->get();` returns an array.
As `id` maybe the unique key, so try this

```
$pin = Inspirations::where('id', $pin['inspiration_id'])->first();
```

If `id` is the primary key, then make it simple

```
$pin = Inspirations::find($pin['inspiration_id']);
```